# Regarding $\mathbb{R \times R}$ as an $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$-module under the ordinary matrix multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

My professor said this statement:
"set of linear transformations on  $\mathbb{R \times R}$ is a subring of End($\mathbb{R \times R}$), and it is isomorphic to the $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, we can regard $\mathbb{R \times R}$ as an $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$-module under the ordinary matrix multiplication " could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: What is it you have trouble understanding? If $m\in M_2(\Bbb R)$ and $x\in \Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ (as a column vector), then ordinary matrix multiplication gives $mx\in \Bbb R\times \Bbb R$. This relationship should satisfy the proerties of a (left) module.

Comment: A $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ multiplied by a two-vector $\mathbf{x}$ produces another two-vector $A\mathbf{x}$.  This satisfies all the module axioms.

Comment: Clarify *what*? You have been told that $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ becomes an $M_2(\mathbb R)$ module when you use normal matrix multiplication. Do you doubt it? That would be fair. *What part* do you doubt? What axiom? If you don't know, then you have not thought about the problem long enough...

Comment: Why are the linear maps only a subset of $\text{End}(\Bbb{R})$? What other maps are you considering in this course?

Comment: we are at the beginning of the course, so I do not know what other maps we will use in the course , the course name is modules.@Chickenmancer

Comment: @rschwieb  yes I doubt all the statements that are said(they are 3) and I want to prove each statement to be sure, I asked about the first statement but the answers were not clear for me and now I am asking about the second and third one ( each statement is separated by a comma).

Comment: @Randall How? could you explain the details please? or suggest a book that contain the details please?

Comment: @Intuition For the first statement, every linear transformation is *a fortiori* a group endomorphism of $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$. So to prove it's a subring, you prove it's closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: @Arthur could you please prove for me that this relationship  should satisfy the properties of a (left) module? certainly if you have time

Comment: @Intuition The properties of a left module is a relatively short list of algebraic properties that must be fulfilled (along the lines of "For all $m, n \in M_2(\Bbb R)$ and $x\in \Bbb R\times \Bbb R$, we have $(nm)x = n(mx)$"). They should each be possible to confirm in a single row of calculations, especially if you're allowed to use what you already know about matrix multiplication (specifically the existence of an identity matrix and that matrix multiplication is associative and distributive over addition).

Comment: @Intuition:  Arthur's comments are all you need.

Comment: @rschwieb what about the second and third statement?

Comment: @Intuition The second you will find in every linear algebra book ever written, and the third is just routine verification. I'm sure you will have no problem finding dozens of detailed proofs of the second one, without me repeating it. What are you stuck with on the third one?

Comment: Now , Is $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ an additive abelian subgroup of $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ ? I think  the ring action properties in the  third one is so easy may be I am not stucked in any step of it @rschwieb

Comment: @Intuition There are lots of copies of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ in $M_2(R)$. If it helps you, you could take the copy consisting of the matrices with zeros on the bottom row to be one copy. Then matrix multiplication on the right gives a right $R$ module structure. But you could do the same thing with a $1\times 2$ matrix with $2\times 2$ matrices acting on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $V = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ to be the set of $2 \times 1$ column vectors.  Multiplying a $2 \times 2$ matrix with a $2 \times 1$ matrix yields another $2 \times 1$ matrix so we have an action $\mathbb M_2(\mathbb R) \times V \to V$.  Because matrix multiplication is associative and distributes over addition this will satisfy all the axioms required of an $\mathbb M_2(\mathbb R)$-module.

Not sure if you've talked about things in this generality yet, but $\mathbb R$ is a field and any ring containing a copy of $\mathbb R$ in its center is called an $\mathbb R$-algebra.  If $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $A$ is an $\mathbb R$-algebra then an $A$-module structure on $V$ is the same thing as having a ring homomorphism $A \to \text{End}_{\mathbb R}(V)$.  In particular, if you take $A$ to be a subring of $\text{End}_{\mathbb R}(V)$ then $V$ is automatically an $A$-module.

Matricies of the form $rI_2 \in \mathbb M_2(\mathbb R)$, where $r \in \mathbb R$ and $I_2$ is the identity matrix, are a copy of $\mathbb R$ in the center of $\mathbb M_2(\mathbb R)$ so $\mathbb M_2(\mathbb R)$ is an $\mathbb R$-algebra.  An unnecessarily complicated way of giving $V = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ the structure of a $\mathbb M_2(\mathbb R)$-module is to say it's the module structure that arises from the ring homomorphism $\mathbb M_2(\mathbb R) \to \text{End}_{\mathbb R}(V)$ (which is actually an isomorphism) one gets by choosing a basis.  This might be what your instructor meant.  But as I said that's overly complicated.  It's much easier to just say "matrix multiplication" and be done with it.

Comment: No, we have not talked about things in this generality yet.

Comment: I did not understand the second and third paragraph ....  could you please, if you do not mind certainly, divide my question into 3 sentences(the sentences are separated by commas) and prove them by the most simple way  that can be used?